# Ionic 3 error when building for Android

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

Good day all,

I've been having issues on my MacBook when trying to build an android app. When I "ionic cordova build android" I get the following error at the end:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
    > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
        > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
          Required by:
              project :
           > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
              > com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/impl/XMLEntityManager
```

I've tried to search for solutions online for over a week now but I still can't get the fix to my problem. I've got a similar setup on my iMac and everything works well there. I've removed and added the platform numerous times but still nothing...
Here is my Ionic info:

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.3
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.2
Node       : v6.11.3
npm        : 3.10.10
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue is related to gradle and only android uses gradle for  build. That's why you are able to build it fine in iOS. Try out this link - http://mitzen.blogspot.in/2017/01/ionic2-cordova-build-android-unable.html

Comment: I think you must update ionic/app-scripts and other thing to the latest, remove and add platform, then try to build again